# PHP post search

Tags: php, search

So i'm making search page for api that i use. And i use two pages one is on the index and one is the search page itself but i have on problem on the search page because it seems nothing go through POST. And i get either blank search page or some random stuff that has not been entered in the search box.
This is the code=>

Part of the index page where i have search form:

```
 <form id='search_form' method='POST' action='index.php'>
    <input id="topSearchText" class="inputText" type="text" size="30" onfocus="this.value=''"          value="Search" style="color: rgb(119, 119, 119);"/>
    <input type="image" name="search_movies" value="Search" src="./images/search.png"/>
  </form>
```

and this is the php on the search.php

```
if(isset($_POST['search_movies']))
     {
        $movie=$tmdb->searchMovie($_POST['search_movies']);
        foreach ($movie['results'] as $value) {
            $filepath = $value['poster_path'];
            $image_url = $tmdb->getImageUrl($filepath, TMDb::IMAGE_POSTER, 'w92');
    echo "...";
}
```

If someone could know what the problem is i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a name on the text box you're entering text into and use that post variable to get the text on the server side.

```
<input name="movie" type="image" name="search_movies" value="Search" src="./images/search.png"/>
...
$movie=$tmdb->searchMovie($_POST['movie']);
```

Comment: This did the job. I tried something similar but did not work so i thought i'm doing something wrong. Thank you